# My 2-year-old does not eat except drinking milk

Tags: toddler, food

My child is going to be 2 in the next 15 days but he likes to drink only milk and does not eat. He will eat only 1 or 2 bites and then will not eat. My pediatrician asked to remove milk. We tried but he cries for milk only. I tried feeding him all kinds of food. He will eat only rice and lentils half a bowl, but only once a day. Rest all he just want milk. Can someone guide me how to gradually remove milk and add food and how to handle the tantrums during that time?

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the advise. This time I will make sure I do not surrender to his tantrums. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your pediatrician has stated, get rid of the milk. Your child doesn't understand the repercussions of an unfulfilling diet where as we, adults, do. He may want to continue drinking milk but doing so, he is not getting provided with the nutrients a growing toddler requires.

The way I previously did it for my three past-milk-phase-drinking children was a day was selected and on that day, no more milk. Bottles were washed once more and put away. We informed the kids that this was going to happen, even if they didn't fully understand. After that, *there was no more milk*, tantrums or not.

A temporary tantrum is well worth it in order for him to begin a healthier, more fulfilling diet suited for a child his age. Don't give in to the tantrum. Eventually he will get hungry and he will realize that milk time is done.

- Pick a day (say 3-5 days from now) to stop giving him milk.
- Inform him of the day as best as you can so he knows that that day is the end of milk.
- On that day, wash the bottles and wrap them up in a bag or something to conceal them and put them away. Don't put them in their usual spot. Put them somewhere that feels like permanent storage (a closet shelf or top of the pantry).
- Deal with the tantrums for now and continue offering other sources of food. "I know you can't have milk but here, I have some rice."